# Jboss Quickstart using Maven (jboss-as:deploy)

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss

I am new to Maven, I am trying to go through the EAP(JBoss) clusterhasingleton quick start guide.

**http://www.jboss.org//quickstarts/eap/cluster-ha-singleton/index.html**

I can deploy the jar and everything works fine by running

**mvn clean install jboss-as:deploy**

I need someone to please explain what does "Deploy" mean in Maven/EAP as i have used JBoss 5 and deployment in that version meant copying the jar in deployments folder(i was using ant) where as i can't find the jar file in the deployments folder in EAP although everything is working.

I can see the jars in the local repository in .m2 folder and target folder in the workspace. How does Jboss know that is deployed? and does it look at the local repository and how?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Why does it matter?

In any case the maven repo is not relevant. In JBoss 5/6, placing applications in the "deploy" directory would indicate to JBoss that those applications should be deployed. 
You can do the same thing in JBossAS 7.x (aka EAP 6) and WildFly 8.x using the "deployments" directory.

It's important to understand that deployments are not in-situ. The actual deployment is stored in a virtual file system. The deployment is written directly to this VFS when you use the maven tool.

The deployment process is much more than just copying WAR and EAR artifacts into the server. For instance, servlets, EJBS, JPA components, CDI components and other managed objects get wired up, validated and perhaps made available in JNDI.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But in JBoss 5/6 when i was deploying or undeploying an EJB, it was just about copying a jar or deleting a jar from the deployments folder. Now i can't see whats happening and this is what i want to understand in more details, Can you please point me to something that i can read.